# Getting a complete list of all YouTube videos in a given category

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to get a list of YouTube videos in a category.

This is the travel category, but I see only a few videos, not the complete list:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/Travel/

Is there a way to get a more complete list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead; the way you are doing it, it could be mistaking the category for a tag, so instead, explicitly state it's a category:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=Travel

Comment: But it still gives me just a few of them, not all. So just like what I had before. Are you seeing different results :)